# cc1plus error: output filename specified twice

Tags: c++, makefile

Trying to compile a system used for my masters project but running into difficulty.
I believe this is supposed to compile correctly so I assume the error falls under something I have done wrong and not with code base itself?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Commands I have entered:

```
$ mkdir obj
$ cd obj
$ ../configure CC=gcc-4.6 CXX=g++-4.6
$ OPT="-O0 -DMODE=0" make
```

Output from make below:

```
make -C util
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/util'
make CFLAGS="-O4 -DUSE_RDTSC=0" pp_time.o
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/util'
cc -O4 -DUSE_RDTSC=0   -c -o pp_time.o ../../util/pp_time.c
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/util'
mv pp_time.o pp_time_us.o
ar crv libtime_us.a pp_time_us.o
a - pp_time_us.o
ranlib libtime_us.a
make CFLAGS="-O4 -DUSE_RDTSC=1" pp_time.o
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/util'
cc -O4 -DUSE_RDTSC=1   -c -o pp_time.o ../../util/pp_time.c
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/util'
mv pp_time.o pp_time_cy.o
ar crv libtime_cy.a pp_time_cy.o
a - pp_time_cy.o
ranlib libtime_cy.a
make CFLAGS="-O4 -DUSE_RDTSC=0 -DUSE_MARSS" pp_time.o
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/util'
cc -O4 -DUSE_RDTSC=0 -DUSE_MARSS   -c -o pp_time.o ../../util/pp_time.c
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/util'
mv pp_time.o pp_time_marss.o
ar crv libtime_marss.a pp_time_marss.o
a - pp_time_marss.o
ranlib libtime_marss.a
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/util'
make -C scheduler
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/scheduler'
if [ ! -f mangled.h ] ; then ../../scheduler/xfn.sh /dev/null > mangled.h ; fi
g++-4.6 -g -O2 -Wall -o0 -DMODE=0 -I -I/scheduler -I/swan -I.. -I../scheduler -std=c++0x -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -S ../../scheduler/wf_stack_frame.cc -o wf_stack_frame.s
cc1plus: error: output filename specified twice
make[1]: *** [wf_stack_frame.s] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/scheduler'
make: *** [scheduler-dir] Error 2
```

Comment: -S is not supposed to be there in g++ options.

Comment: Should I remove -S and its argument from the Makefile then?

Comment: The simple dirty way is to edit `Makefile` at /home/jordan/workspace/swan/obj/scheduler and remove -S from there. But the good solution will be to fix your automake scripts.

Comment: Removing the -S resulted in the same output only with this as the error:
g++-4.6: error: o0: No such file or directory

Comment: You have `-o0` which should be `-O0` that is "hyphen Capital alphabet O followed by 0". Perhaps you should remove `-o0` as you already have `-O2` in the options.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sundar your comments led to me correcting the problem. 
If you want to go ahead and make an answer with your latest comment I will accept and mark closed.

Answer (score 2):

```
g++-4.6 -g -O2 -Wall -o0 -DMODE=0 -I -I/scheduler -I/swan -I.. -I../scheduler -std=c++0x -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -S ../../scheduler/wf_stack_frame.cc -o wf_stack_frame.s
cc1plus: error: output filename specified twice
```

The problem is that you have `-o0` in your command which specifies your output filename to be `0` which conflicts with `-o wf_stack_frame.s`. This must be `-O0 [capital letter O]`. You already have `-O2` in the command you could remove that and use `-O0` or vice-versa. Remember if you mention both, then the last option will be effective.